# Dynamic margin for button

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am creating a desktop application using WPF.
I have placed three elements in a row: Button, Textbox and Label.
When I resize the screen, margin for Label and Textbox is consistent, but not for the Button. Button gets shrunk and stretched according to the screen height.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, when the screen height is greater, the Button is bigger and vice versa.

Here is the code:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="Search: (Name or Contact)" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,25,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="auto" Margin="25,0,25,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20"  Grid.Row="0" Name="TxtSearch" TextChanged="TxtSearch_TextChanged"/>
    <Button x:Name="BtnSearch"  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="20" Click="BtnSearch_Click" Margin="32">
        <Viewbox>
            <TextBlock>
                Search
            </TextBlock>
        </Viewbox>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

I want button height to be consistent and margin to be dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to go about this.

You could, for example, set `VerticalAlignment` of the Button to `Center`, and in normal circumstances it would work.  However, you have a `Viewbox` as its content, and inside of it a `TextBlock`.  Well, that `Viewbox`, the way you have it set up right now, will re-size depending on the window size.  If you choose the `VerticalAlignment` approach, I suggest to simply set button's `Content` to your "Search" text: `Content="Search"`.

If you wish to keep that `Viewbox`, you could set the height of the button to a static value and that will most certainly prevent it from being re-sized vertically.  However, I'm not a huge fan of static dimensions in such scenarios.

I'm not entirely sure why you have the `Viewbox` there, but those are the two easiest approaches thus far.  Unless you have a specific reason for having a `Viewbox` as the button's content, I would remove it, as it'll cause you unnecessary problems. `Viewbox` has its uses, but I don't think this is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

When you are defining a grid, you have 3 posibilities for the width/height

- Fixed size
- Auto (Expand to the size of the content)
- Star (Take as much space as available)

So in your case where Button is placed in Grid.Row="0", make that row a fixed size. If you are only defining one row in the grid, i suggest you make another row with a 'star' height. Then place the viewbox in the row.